# Is there a way to implement nested routes with the equivalent <Outlet /> of react in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've searched a lot about this, but I think I've hit the rock bottom. I'm not sure what to search anymore since English isn't my native language. All the results I get is about how to make sub folders to get nested routes in ***NextJS***. My question is that in vanilla **ReactJS**, we have the following route configuration:

```
<Routes> 
   <Route path="/welcome" element={<Welcome />}>
     <Route path="/welcome/new-user" element={<p>Welcome new user!</p>} />
   </Route>
</Routes>
```

and in the `Welcome.js` component, we have :

```
<section>
  <h2>Welcome Page!</h2>
  <Outlet />
</section>
```

is there a way to implement such thing in ***NextJS***? Thanks

Comment: Okay, it seems NextJS v13 introduced a featured for this, and it can be done in the new app directory with Layout.js special file to have child routes

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to add nested routes in NextJS, in a simple way.
The way NextJS routes work is based on the folders and files in the pages folder

For example:

[image: Folder structure in NextJS]

With this structure you will end up with this route:

HTTP://localhost:3000/items/99099/update - to access the update page

or

HTTP://localhost:3000/items/99099 - to access the index page.

**With your welcome example it would look like this**:

[image: NextJS folder structure with another nested route example]

Hope I've solved your issue, but if you still have some doubts I found this [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nfAxNTmme64) video that may help you

Comment: Thanks for the gesture, but I meant like really a route component page being rendered inside of another route component page. Just like how <Outlet /> component works in plain react apps

Comment: That's not possible since NextJS doesn't have any route component such as react-router does, the only way to render pages with routes are with folders and subfolders, maybe you can render a page inside another page with next/link or just returning the page JSX